# parsing JSON in java?

Tags: java, json

How to parsing JSON in java?

```
{
    "code": 100,
    "message": "SUCCESS",
    "result": {
        "list": [
            {
                "cardNumber": "ALUFZZ5SZ1Q5",
                "expireTime": 1270742400,
                "surplusThreshold": 4,
                "uid": 771292,
                "useTime": 1270214375,
                "wareId": 1145
            },
            {
                "cardNumber": "ALUFZZ5SZ1QD",
                "expireTime": 1270828800,
                "surplusThreshold": 7,
                "uid": 784289,
                "useTime": 1270302200,
                "wareId": 1145
            },
            {
                "cardNumber": "ALUFZZ5SZ1RC",
                "expireTime": 1270828800,
                "surplusThreshold": 10,
                "uid": 773664,
                "useTime": 1270300871,
                "wareId": 1145
            },
            {
                "cardNumber": "ALUFZZ5SZ1UM",
                "expireTime": 1270828800,
                "surplusThreshold": 10,
                "uid": 779560,
                "useTime": 1270282841,
                "wareId": 1145
            },
            {
                "cardNumber": "ALUFZZ5SZ1VT",
                "expireTime": 1270656000,
                "surplusThreshold": 2,
                "uid": 754099,
                "useTime": 1270106775,
                "wareId": 1145
            }
        ],
        "pageCount": 61,
        "pageIndex": 2,
        "pageSize": 5,
        "recordCount": 308
    }
}
```

Comment: Search on the forum before asking. Exact duplicate?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library/338933#338933

Comment: The first step would be searching StackOverflow, or simply clicking one of the many related question listed while posting the question. Then, if that does not help, post your question with a lot more detail or the problem you are trying to solve. "How to parse JSON" is quite vague! You will need to tell os what you want it parsed into.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the examples in [gson-user-guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

[Download Site](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

More json libraries are listet at [json.org](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I have had good results with the [StringTree JSON](http://www.stringtree.org/stringtree-json.html) library.